# Fastboot doesn't recognize moto g 4g on linux

Tags: linux, fastboot, motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G 4g. ADB recognizes the cell and I can restart it in fastboot mode, but when I check in the terminal with:

```
fastboot devices
```

Nothing appears, and if I go on with

```
fastboot oem get_unlock_data
```

It gets stuck at

```
< waiting for device >
```

I tried as a user and as root on an Archlinux machine with android-udev rules as shown in the [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/android#Adding_udev_Rules).

Comment: What is the status of Bootloader? Locked or unlocked?

Comment: It's locked, according to the ap fastboot flash mode

Comment: It must be unlocked for continuing. Visit XDA developers forums for more info.

Comment: How did you manage to resolve the waiting for device issue?